# What fails in constructing a homotopy category out of candidate triangles in a triangulated category?

Tags: triangulated-categories

Following Neeman's article "New axioms for triangulated categories", for a triangulated category $\mathscr T$ let $CT(\mathscr T)$ denote the category of *candidate triangles*, i.e. diagrams
\begin{equation}X\overset f\to Y\overset g\to Z\overset h\to \Sigma X\quad (*)\end{equation}
such that $gf=0$, $hg=0$ and $(\Sigma f)h=0$, with morphisms being commutative diagrams between such triangles.
We can define homotopy of maps between candidate triangles to be chain homotopy and there is an automorphism $\tilde\Sigma\colon CT(\mathscr T)\to CT(\mathscr T)$ which takes $(*)$ to
$$Y\overset{-g}\to Z\overset{-h}\to \Sigma X\overset{-\Sigma f}\to \Sigma Y.$$
We can define mapping cones as in a usual chain complex category, and a lot of the usual results hold for this category (e.g. homotopic maps have isomorphic mapping cones).

What I fail to see, is why the mapping cone construction along with $\tilde\Sigma$ does not give rise to a triangulation of $CT(\mathscr T)$?

Comment: I would guess that Toda brackets give a counterexample to the long exact sequence axiom, similarly to https://mathoverflow.net/a/379112 .